# Mysql tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size are not working

Tags: mysql

I set the table tmp size to a higher value in my `my.cnf` file like this:

```
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
```

But it's not working.  I used this [**script**](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) to check it.  Even after I reboot, it is still showing that 16M is the default value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to make sure the settings go under the `[mysqld]` group in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
```

then do one of two things:

OPTION 1 : Restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

OPTION 2 : Set it globally for new incoming connections (restart not required)

```
SET GLOBAL tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
SET GLOBAL max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: worth noting that `SET GLOBAL ...` does not persist a service restart, (at least in 5.0, not tried this in 5.5).

Comment: @Oneiroi That why I said first add the variables to my.cnf under the `[mysqld]` group header. Then, set them dynamically in case a restart was not possible during normal business hours...

Comment: ah that's what I get for skim reading, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from your my.cnf.

```
[mysqld]
...
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M
...
```

Should resolve the issue, I've been caught out by this in the past myself.